# Calculating/Detecting sizes in LESS

Tags: html, css, less

I have the following problem:
I have two divs, nested in another one.

```
<div id="parent" style="height: 100%;">
    <div id="child1">bla</div>
    <div id="child2" style="height: 20px;">bla</div>
</div>
```

Now is there a way (without javascript) to expand #div1 dynamically to the maximum (380px)? height: 100% would expand it to the 400px of the parent. Overflowed content in #div1 should be scrolled.

I'm new to LESS and hoped that it might be possible with that (e.g. child1.height=#parent.height-#child2.height)?

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you dont want javascript, but not sure if you mean raw JS or you dont even want embedded JS in less, if you dont mind embedding logic you can use javascript to populate variables in LESS like so:

```
@desiredHeight = getElementById("parent").style("height") - getElementById("child2").style("height");
#child1 { height: @desiredHeight; }
```

Syntax may not be right as im doing it off the top of my head but something like that should work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip. unfortunately it returns null for the elements. Why is that? the correct syntax should be: `@child1Height: &document.getElementById('parent').offsetHeight-document.getElementById('child2').offsetHeight+'px'&;` (Replace the & with `)

Comment: Could be that you less.js file is being loaded before the DOM has finished loading, could be because the id's are not correct, or you are simply putting duff data into the @child1Height variable so it doesn't know how to use it in the css.

Answer (score 1):

If the less.js you are using does not support JavaScript evaluation inside *.less files, go for server side LESS implementation.